# C# Getting value from sql query by SqlDataRader multiplying by columns count

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM ExampleTable
```

`ExampleTable` has 7 columns. I want to get specific columns values, for example: second and fourth. For that I'm using a `SqlDataReader` like that:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,conn))
{
    using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if(reader != null)
        {
            var firstvalue = "";
            var fourthvalue = "";

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                firstvalue = reader[1].ToString();
                fourthvalue = reader[3].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to show those values in console, it's multiplying by columns count, app writes firstvalue and fourthvalues seven times. How to fix it? Any ideas?

EDIT:

I've commented code below this one and its ok now. Anyway, thanks for your advices.

Comment: Why not specify these column names instead of * in select query if you need only specific columns?

Comment: @fanarek instead of `*` why can't you select your required columns?

Comment: Of course I can, but the question is: Will it multiply as before ?

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your posted code. Something may be incorrect with your printing number logic. Can you show us your printing logic?

Answer (score 0):

Check result of your query `SELECT * FROM ExampleTable`  in SQL Query Analyzer.It may be duplicate values in database. If not , please post your code for console printing.